# What is ToSession/FromSession alternative in PowerShell 4

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm currently working on a database refresh automation project. I need to copy a SQL bak file(probably around 100 GB) from the production environment to the development environment by using PowerShell script.

However, the production environment uses PowerShell 4.0 instead of PowerShell 5.0, so I cannot use ToSession/FromSession on it. Restarting the production environment is not allowed, so I cannot just update the PowerShell version to 5.0. The platform I'm using is Windows Server 2012 R2 Any advise I can still do this action without affecting the OS too much?

Comment: Is the file available on a UNC path?

Comment: No. The bak file cannot be found using UNC path. Even using the Copy-Item command to it, it still have to be used as administrator.